# Is there a different way to grab a thumbnail image than this?

Tags: images, upgrade

I am currently upgrading my WP to 3.2.1 to 3.5.2, and for one section of my posts it seems like the featured image has disappeared. However, I just checked the the wp_posts table in the database through phpmyadmin and looked for one of my posts that had this issue. My `img` tags are being produced dynamically, but the problem is that the `src` is blank. Here's an example of one of the posts:

Given this record in my wp_posts table:

```
    ID     post_author  post_date   post_date_gmt   post_content    post_title  post_excerpt    post_status     comment_status  ping_status     post_password   post_name   to_ping     pinged  post_modified   post_modified_gmt   post_content_filtered   post_parent     guid                                                 menu_order     post_type   post_mime_type  comment_count   cod_current_ahrf 
    16169  1            2011-06-17  2011-06-17                      Nick-Arias                  inherit         close           close                           Nick-Arias.jpg          0000-00-00 00:00:00     0000-00-00 00:00:00                         3728            /images/ahrf/pioneers/legends_face/Nick-Arias.jpg    0              attachment  image/jpeg      0
```

category-legends.php:

```
if(file_exists($_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}.substr($fivesdraft->guid_legend,20)))
    {
    echo $fivesdraft->ID; // returns 3728
    $featured = gangmei_get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $fivesdraft->ID );          
    echo '<li class="legends-thumb"><div class="img-wrapper"><a href="/?legends='.$fivesdraft->post_name.'"><img src="'.$featured.'" alt="'.$fivesdraft->name.'" /></div><p><a href="/?legends='.$fivesdraft->post_name.'">'.$fivesdraft->name.'</a></p></li>';
    }
```

functions.php:

```
    function gangmei_get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id = NULL) {
        global $id;
        $post_id = (NULL === $post_id) ? $id : $post_id;
        $edmund = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
        echo "post_id = $post_id"; // returns 3728
        echo "edmund = $edmund"; // returns 16169
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id), 'full'); //the issue arises here. this returns nothing.
        $src = $src[0];
        return $src;

    }
```

This is what is produced: `<img src="" alt="Nick Arias">`. What's supposed to be produced is this: `<img alt="Nick Arias" src="/images/ahrf/pioneers/legends_face/Nick-Arias.jpg">`

The thing is that under the `guid` column in the database you can see the value of that column for that record is `/images/ahrf/pioneers/legends_face/Nick-Arias.jpg`. Is it possible to just grab the `guid` instead of going through all of these functions? Like this:

`$featured = $fivesdraft->guid;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. What I did to fix this was simplify the whole thing:

```
if(file_exists($_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}.substr($fivesdraft->guid_legend,20))
    {
    $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($fivesdraft->ID);
    $featured = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );

    //$featured = gangmei_get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $fivesdraft->ID );

    echo '<li class="legends-thumb"><div class="img-wrapper"><a href="/?legends='.$fivesdraft->post_name.'"><img src="'.$featured.'" alt="'.$fivesdraft->name.'" /></div><p><a href="/?legends='.$fivesdraft->post_name.'">'.$fivesdraft->name.'</a></p></li>';
    }
```

No clue why the old version worked for 3.2.1 and not 3.5.2 though.

Comment: Using that `susbstring` like that looks dicey but I can't say for sure without knowing what `$fivesdraft` looks like.

Answer (score 0):

you need to echo it.

example:

```
<?php $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');?>
<img src="<?php echo $src[0] ?>" />
```

Comment: The problem is `$src` isn't returning anything. It's not even an array like it's supposed to be. It's just blank, so echoing it wouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works when I try it with a post ID known to have a "Featured" image. It is possible that you have a database problem but that isn't the table you'd find it, probably. Look in `$wpdb->postmeta` for a k ey named `_thumbnail_id` and a `post_id` matching a post you think should have a thumbnail. If that isn't there your post has lost its "Featured" image somehow and you need to fix that. My guess is that you problem is here.

Jumping from `3.2.1` to `3.5.2` is a huge jump. A lot has changed. If you have a backup of the database, I'd suggest resetting to `3.2.1` and incrementally updating through each release until you get current. If that is not possible you may have to debug and repair problem by problem.

Couple of other things:

> Is it possible to just grab the guid instead of going through all of these functions?

[The `guid` is not an `URL`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Important_GUID_Note). Don't let the fact that it looks like one confuse you.

> Is there a different way to grab a thumbnail image than this?

There are other ways to do it, yes, depending on what you want. You can go straight to complete markup with [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail), for example.

Comment: Thanks sha. I posted my solution as an answer to this question, could you check if it's ok? Will it change anything moving forward or does it work the same?